# How are mouse events dispatched from Cocoa event loop to Carbon windows?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I have a Carbon app with some embedded Cocoa views that I'm trying to gradually port to Cocoa.  The app currently uses a Carbon event loop ( `RunApplicationEventLoop` ), loads its main window from a Carbon nib file, and everything works like a charm.

What I'm trying to do for now is to replace `RunApplicationEventLoop` with `[NSApp run]`.
The application launches correctly and the main window is displayed, however not all events are delivered to the Carbon event handlers. Mouse clicks are only delivered to the Cocoa views that are embedded in that Carbon window, but not to the Carbon event handlers for the window itself.

According to the documentation I foud [here](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/CarbonCocoaIntegration.pdf) Everthing should just work. 
I'm basically looking for:

1. A more detailed documentation of Cocoa/Carbon integration.
2. Ideas for debugging the event dispatch process.

Note: I have tried both `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:]` and replacing the implementation of `NSWindow sendEvent:` (for an NSWindow created with `initWithWindowRef`). Mouse events are definitely arriving there, but not to any Carbon event handlers.

Comment: When embedding a Cocoa view in a Carbon window, the Cocoa view receives the event first, and passes it on to Carbon afterwards. Cocoa uses a responder chain, where each responder in the chain either handles the event, or passes it to the next responder. If you're overriding mouseDown: in your Cocoa view, the mouse down event won't get passed to the next responder unless you call [super mouseDown:]. Is it possible that your cocoa views aren't passing the event to the next responder in the chain? That might cause the event to not get passed to your Carbon windows.